# Reading values from CSV and output them in the format Column1:Row1, Column2:Row1

Tags: csv, powershell, foreach, powershell-3.0, export-to-csv

I am trying to write simple PowerShell code to read two columns values from CSV and print in manner like

```
1

201

2

202
.
.
```

**CSV File:**

```
PRODID  DEVID   Name

1       201    Application

2       202    Product

3       203    Component

4       204    Author

5       205    Version
```

**Powershell Code:**

```
$DEVID = Import-Csv C:\test\install.csv | % {$_.DEVID}
$PRODID = Import-Csv C:\test\install.csv | % {$_.PRODID}

ForEach ($DEVI in $DEVID)
{
    Write-Host $DEVI

    ForEach ($PRODI in $PRODID)
    {[enter image description here][1]
      Write-Host $PRODI     
    }
}
```

But I am not getting expected output, though I have tried break, continue syntax. 
Can anyone help me in this case please?

Comment: `{$_.PRODID}` instead of `{$.PRODID}`

Comment: Thank you Micky for your reply, but I am able to read the values from CSV but not in the format I am expecting. The second foreach loop continues unless it finished reading values from second column.

Comment: Each ProdID has a unique DevID?

Comment: yes, each ProdID has unique DevID. The current code gives me output like 201->1->2->3->4->5; 202->1->2->3->4->5....... (-> nextline). so it does not go back to first foreach loop until second foreach finishes reading all values from second column)

Comment: try `Import-Csv C:\test\install.csv | % { write-host $_.PRODID;write-host $_.DEVID}`

Comment: Is your CSV tab separated?

Comment: @MartinBrandl - Yes

Comment: @MickyBalladelli - That works! Thank you. But I want to read the values in this manner within ForEach as I have to perform some other actions too so is there any way to read the values in same manner within ForEach? I want to read values like $a=201, $b=1 then write $a and $b values to another XML file. Sorry for asking to much.

Comment: you can use Martin's example and assign new variables or write directly to the other XML file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to import your csv once. Then just iterate over it and output your desired records:

```
Import-Csv 'C:\test\install.csv' | Foreach { 
   $_.PRODID; $_.DEVID; 
}
```

**Output:**

```
1
201
2
202
3
203
4
204
5
205
```

If this doesn't work, you have to show us your csv file.

Comment: Here is the CSV file:

PRODID  DEVID   Name

1       201    Application

2       202    Product

3       203    Component

4       204    Author

5       205    Version

Comment: can you upload your csv? It seems like the Import-CSV cmdlet cannot read it properly

Comment: I have attached an image. Let me know if you could see it.

Comment: An image doesn't help. Just upload the csv file anywhere

Comment: You could download that CSV from here https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B_nT-fWGxEw3bjVGNnJMMFBSYU0&usp=sharing

Let me put the whole scenario here to give your clear picture of what I have been trying to achieve, I am trying to read values of two columns from CSV (first and second column) for each value in second column should be searched in test.xml file, if found the value should be replaced by same row of first column. For e.g Script should read 201 from csv, search in test.xml, if found, 201 should be replaced by 1.

Comment: You have a csv, not a tsv. I updated my answer please try it. To solve your whole problem you should post another question (after you tried it yourself) *and* show us the content of the text.xml since the answer will depend on it.

Comment: Thank you Martin and Micky. I have tried Import-Csv $csvpath | % { $PROD = $_.PRODID;$DEV = $_.DEVID 
<my code>
}
Looks working as expected. Great help. Thank you again.

Comment: You are welcome. Please consider accepting the answer.